# How do I handle empty files when dumping ifstream to cout?

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream, ifstream

I'm trying to dump the contents of a file to `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);
        if (fin) {
            std::cout << "---file contents---\n";
            std::cout << fin.rdbuf();
            std::cout << "---end contents---\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "The file does not exist\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " FILE\n";
    }
    if (std::cout.good()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (std::cout.fail()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This code does not work as intended when the input file is empty. It prints the initial "---file contents---", but never prints the trailing "---end contents---". After debugging, I found the application is not crashing, but instead is putting `std::cout` in an error state (the return code is 1).

How can I print the contents of an empty file without putting `cout` in an error state?

Comment: On an unrelated note, there are many possible reasons a file could not be opened, not only that it doesn't exist. :)

Comment: Good point. I suppose my error message is wrong in that case. But if the empty file is opened successfully, I expect `cout << fin.rdbuf()` to just print nothing and move along happily

Comment: Regarding your problem, my guess is that because the file is empty there's nothing to buffer and no buffer is created. That means `rdbuf()` returns a null pointer, and `badbit` is set on the output stream. Check what `rdbuf()` returns first.

Comment: I had a similar hunch, but that is not the case. Checking the result of `rdbuf()` before printing finds the pointer is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This `operator<<` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) (overload number 10 in the list) explains it all:

> If no characters were inserted, executes `setstate(failbit)`.

Since the input file is empty, there's no characters to insert into the output stream. And the `failbit` is set.

You need to add a specific check for `failbit` after

```
std::cout << fin.rdbuf();
```

to see if the input file was empty or not.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. Thanks for your help!